# Time Series Forecasting Incorporating another person's forecast

Tags: time-series, forecasting

Suppose I have a time series y which I want to do a forecast on.

Someoneelse with regression information x which is not available and is unwilling to share with me produces a forecast z of y

Is there anyway I can incorporate z into my forecast of y ?

Comment: You should try to give some more context.  Since the other forecast available to you includes the use of covariate x, It is a proxy for x.  Maybe use arimax, or dynamic linear models. Or, probably the y series and the other forecast y' is cointegrated?

Comment: Yes. It is called ensembling